# ActiveRecord vs. SQL - Is there a cleaner way?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 4 based application that's handling some SIEM style work for us.  I'm a big believer in making code as readable as possible and then worrying about optimization.  I'm finding that attempting to find all of the events that contain a set of words leads to exceptionally poor performance if I rely on AR, so I've resorted to using SQL directly even though it's fragile.

Is there a better way to do the following using AR?

```
sql = "select event_id from events_words where generated>'#{starting_time.to_s(:db)}' and word_id in (select id from words where words.text in ('#{terms.join("', '")}')) group by event_id having count(distinct(word_id))=#{terms.count}"
```

`events_words` is a join table containing the `word_id` for every word in every event, the `event_id` for each event and `generated`, the timestamp when the event was generated.  The generated field is being used to limit search results to a time frame and the table itself is partitioned by date to keep the indices to a size that can fit in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

For even better performance and readability, consider using a JOIN operation in place of the `IN (subquery)`. To improve readability, consider qualifying *every* column reference.

Personally, I would find this statement to be much more "readable":

```
       SELECT e.event_id 
         FROM events_words e
         JOIN ( SELECT w.id
                  FROM words w
                 WHERE w.text IN ('#{terms.join("', '")}')
              ) s
           ON s.id = e.word_id
        WHERE e.generated > '#{starting_time.to_s(:db)}'
        GROUP BY e.event_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e.word_id))=#{terms.count}
```

... ("readability" gauged in terms of the ability of the reader to quickly figure out what the query is doing).

As to getting a query like that done in ActiveRecord (if that's possible), I am inclined to pity the poor soul that has to wade through whatever that looks like to decipher what the query is actually doing.

---

**EDIT**

After reviewing again, I see there's no need for the inline view. (That was generated from the subquery during my initial change to the JOIN operation, but that's not really necessary.

This should return an equivalent result:

```
       SELECT e.event_id 
         FROM events_words e
         JOIN words w
           ON w.id = e.word_id
        WHERE e.generated > '#{starting_time.to_s(:db)}'
          AND w.text IN ('#{terms.join("', '")}')
        GROUP BY e.event_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(e.word_id))=#{terms.count}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the join and see how it works out for performance!

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I'm hoping that someone else will be able to help you with the ActiveRecord re-write. (I didn't really help answer the question you asked.) And maybe the AR query won't be as horrendous as I think it's going to be. (I'd like to believe there'd be an elegant way to express the query you want to run, but I don't have any evidence to support such a belief.) Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan. And be sure that suitable indexes are available, for example, `ON event_words (event_id,  word_id, generated)` and `ON words (text,id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
EventWord.joins(:word).
          where(:words => {:text => terms}).
          where("generated > ?", :starting_time).
          group(:event_id).
          having("count(distinct(word_id)) = ?", terms.count).
          select(:event_id)
```

Or ...

```
Event.joins(:word).
      where(:words => {:text => terms}).
      where("generated > ?", :starting_time).
      group(:id).
      having("count(distinct(words.id)) = ?", terms.count)
```

Comment: Oooooo... That looks ARish!  I'll let you know.

Comment: Actually, this would require that the join table itself has a model, which it does not...  Typically, these are based on habtm relations in the individual models...  Simply creating an `event_word.rb` model inheriting from AR will not solve this, I don't think...?

Comment: Perhaps try the additional Event-based expression.